# Not able to dump data.Json serializable issue

Tags: python, json

```
import json

newdic={"name":"John","age":30,"cars": [{ "name":"Ford", "models":["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },{ "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5"] },{ "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }]}

 with open('newjson','w') as pointer:
 json.dumps(pointer,newdic)
```

I am new to json  and getting error while doing json dump.

```
json.dump(pointer,newdic)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 178, in dump
for chunk in iterable:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 436, in _iterencode
o = _default(o)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") TypeError: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='newjson' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> is not JSON serializable
```

can you please tell me which  all object do json support?

Comment: You're using `dumps` in your code and even for `dump` the argument ordering is incorrect.

Comment: Your dict is also broken. You're missing a double-quote before _Fiesta_

Comment: @MrGrj sorry for that .that was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You need to call [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.dump), not json.dumps.
2. You got the order of arguments wrong.  It's `json.dump(obj, fp)`, not `json.dump(fp, obj)`

Comment: can you please tell me when to use dump and dumps?

Comment: `dump` when you write to a file.